# Kotlin - Pass "this" as a constructor argument

Tags: kotlin, constructor

I'm writing a binary tree class. I want to avoid `null` values, and I decided to use a designated value `nil`. So, when an element doesn't have a left child, instead of `n.left = null` I have `n.left = nil`. But, I need to specify the left and the right child for `nil`, and the only choice is `nil` itself. So, I want to write this:

```
class Node(val left: Node, val right: Node) {
    companion object {
        val nil = Node(nil, nil)
    }
}
```

or at most:

```
class Node(val left: Node, val right: Node) {
    private constructor(): this(this, this)
    companion object {
        val nil = Node()
    }
}
```

Those don't compile, of course. This is what I'm forced to write:

```
class Node {
    val left: Node
    val right: Node
    constructor(left: Node, right: Node) {
        this.left = left
        this.right = right
    }
    private constructor() {
        this.left = this
        this.right = this
    }
    companion object {
        val nil = Node()
    }
}
```

It has much more code, especially after I'll add more fields. Any way to write this concisely?

Comment: Since a type being nullable is part of Kotlin's type system, it forces you to handle the case where a value may be null. There's also smart casting which is very helpful in local contexts. And null is a good value to represent "no value". In short, why do you want to avoid using null values? All you seem to be doing is replacing `if (foo == null)` with `if (foo == Node.nil`), while also losing the use of the `?.` and `?:` operators.

Comment: Without `null` what you want would be an infinitely sized recursive type

Comment: @Slaw, I can prove that, after initial checks, nulls can't appear anywhere. While I indeed can use null checks, `?.`, and `?:`, the resulting code was very clunky (even with smart casting). In the current version (due to some additional offtopic stuff), `if (foo == Node.nil)` only appears where it is indeed unavoidable (e.g. when inserting a new node). In most functions, it's not required.

Comment: Some of your awkward code code with nullables might be cleaned up by creating extension functions for nullable receivers, for example `fun Node?.foo() { //...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Disclaimer:** I would reconsider your avoidance of null. [Nullability](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-nullable-types) is built into Kotlin's type system, and null is a good representation of "no value". Plus, Kotlin has the [safe call](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls) (`?.`) and [elvis](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) (`?:`) operators and has [smart casting](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#smart-casts), which works with [checks for null](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#checking-for-null-in-conditions).*

---

If you want to avoid nullable types, then perhaps something like this would work for you:

```kotlin
sealed interface Node {
    val left: Node
    val right: Node
}

object EmptyNode : Node {
    override val left: EmptyNode get() = this
    override val right: EmptyNode get() = this
}

class RegularNode(
    override val left: Node = EmptyNode,
    override val right: Node = EmptyNode,
) : Node
```

But it will require you to update two implementations for every property and function you add to the `Node` interface. Though you could make use of extension functions where possible.

That said, I assume you'll be adding a `value` property to `Node`. And given the nature of your use case, this property will have to be generic. That makes things more difficult, though you could try something like this:

```kotlin
val Node<*>.isEmptyNode: Boolean
    get() = this is EmptyNode<*>

sealed interface Node<T> {
    val left: Node<T>
    val right: Node<T>
    val value: T
}

class EmptyNode<T> : Node<T> {
    override val left: EmptyNode<T> get() = this
    override val right: EmptyNode<T> get() = this
    override val value: Nothing
        get() = throw IllegalStateException("EmptyNode has no value")
}

class RegularNode<T>(
    override val value: T,
    override val left: Node<T> = EmptyNode(),
    override val right: Node<T> = EmptyNode(),
) : Node<T>
```

But note now `EmptyNode` is not a singleton.

Comment: While I don't think it's more concise, it indeed looks cleaner. I see your point about `T` - I made some functions return `T?`, but it's not a good idea.

Comment: I may have found a way to implement a `value` property of type `T`. It might work for you. See updates. But I, personally, would reconsider the avoidance of `null`.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to rewrite with nulls.